# Duration between two or more time intervals (in PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, logic

I have time interval as below,

```
1-  07:00:00 to 09:30:00 (duration 02:30:00)
2-  08:00:00 to 11:00:00 (duration 03:00:00)
```

But actual combined duration is 07:00:00 - 11:00:00 (Dur 04:00:00). When we are adding 2 individual duration it will give result 5:30:00..like this different combinations may happen(1-7,5-8,9-10,6-9:30) I want a logic to find actual duration without considering intersecting time intervals. If it is already answered kindly give me the path to it. Thanks in Advance.
Note: It is to calculate the duration of work done from attendance data and on duty slips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
enter code here

function compareTimes($start,$end)  
 {
 $count=count($start);
 for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
 {
  for($j=0;$j<$count;$j++)
  {
   if($j==$i)
   {

   }
   elseif($start[$j]>=$start[$i] and $start[$j]<=$end[$i]) 
   {
     if($end[$j]>=$start[$i] and $end[$j]<=$end[$i]) 
     {
       $start[$j]="0";
       $end[$j]="0";
     }  
     else
     {
        $end[$i]=$end[$j];
        $start[$j]="0";
       $end[$j]="0";
     }
   }

  }
 }
 $dur=0;
 $count1=count($start);
 for($i=0;$i<$count1;$i++)
 {
  $dur1=$end[$i]-$start[$i];
  $dur=$dur1+$dur;
 }
  return $dur;   
 }
```

// EXAMPLE FOR THE PERIOD 5-6,4-8 &8-9

```
  $start=array("5","4","8");

  $end=array("6","8","9");
  $check=compareTimes($start,$end);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any automated way to do this, but IMO the best way would be to convert them to an integer (Unix time stamp) and then deal with two at a time. Then you can find the earliest start time and latest end time to work out order, then check to see if the earlier end time overlaps the latest start time.

```
function compareTimes($start1, $end1, $start2, $end2)
{
    $earliest = $start1 <= $start2 ? 1 : 2;
    $latest = $end1 >= $end2 ? 1 : 2;

    if ($earliest == $latest) 
    {
        $end = 'end'.$latest;
        $start = 'start'.$earliest;
        return ($$end - $$start);
    }

    // Check to see if there is any overlap.
    $earlyEnd = 'end'.$earliest;
    $lateStart = 'start'.$latest;
    if ($earlyEnd >= $lateStart)
    {
        $start = 'start'.$earliest;
        $end = 'end'.$latest;
        return ($$end - $$start);
    }
    // If there is no overlap we just total the duration of the two.
    return (($end1 - $start1) + ($end2 - $start2));

}

$start1 = strtotime('01/01/1970 07:00');
$end1 = strtotime('01/01/1970 09:30');
$start2 = strtotime('01/01/1970 08:00');
$end2 = strtotime('01/01/1970 11:00');
$totalDuration = compareTimes($start1, $end1, $start2, $end2);
```

> NB: I haven't tested this code. Please check it before using it in a live environment.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Styphon to lead me to the proper answer..I have posted my answer for more than 2 intervals